# Android animation not working properly

Tags: java, android, animation

I used the following segment of code to animate a balloon. Here the balloon is nothing, but the button  and it is animating using translate animation.

Animation works fine, but while balloon moving some white dots are displaying (See the Image ). Why? Any Solution?

See this Image:

[image]

```
            -------------
    anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 360,1000,-100 );
    anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    anim.setDuration(10000L);
    anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());

    btnBalloon.setAnimation(anim);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not clearing the canvas on each new frame. The dots are the edge of previous instances of the balloon that are still visible.

Each time the canvas is drawn, it does not start from scratch, it draws on top of what's already there. This means that each time the balloon is drawn, it's drawing on top of every other instance of it. I'm guessing your balloon image has a black background? To remedy this, you'll need to 'clear' your canvas, by drawing the background afresh, on each frame. In this case, you'll need to drawn a black rectangle that covers the whole frame, *before* drawing the balloon.